# Okhttp response data NULL

Tags: android, okhttp

```
  @Override
  public void onResponse(String response, int id) {
       try {
           JSONObject pollresult = new JSONObject(response);
           List<OrderInfo> info = new Gson().fromJson(pollresult.getString("data"), new TypeToken<ArrayList<OrderInfo>>() {
           }.getType());
           orderId = info.get(0).getOrderID();
       } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
       }
 }
```

info.get(0) returns null and i get NullPointerException

Comment: So the server returned an OK that either is not JSON, or was an empty/null object in JSON.  Your code should simply handle this possibility -- what's the question/problem?

Comment: i want get "orderId" in the onCreate ,but it is null

Comment: Can you send your log?